# Using guzzle pool with different settings authentication

Tags: authentication, guzzle, pool

I want to use Guzzle which will send a few (~20) requests. I use asyncRequest because I want to send it and wait if all is complete and then continue, it will be probably faster than call each request separately so I use Pool.

The problem is, that I don't know if its possible to call each request with different authentication because Pool has only array with options but it's for all requests.

Is there any other faster solution? Because now response is slow: when I call 20 apis it takes about 25 seconds and more.

I have $api which is class in getHeader() i return [ 'auth'=> ['username','password','digist'] ]

code:

```
        $requests = function ($apis) {
            foreach ($apis as $api)
            {
                yield new Request($api->getTYPE(),$api->getURL(),$api->getHeader());
            }
        };

        $myresponses = new Pool($client,$requests($array_of_external_apis),['concurrency'=>5,
        'fulfilled'=>function($response,$index)
        {

            resultArray[] = $response;
        },
        'rejected'=> function($reason,$index)
        {

            resultArrayFailed[] = $response;
        }]);
        $promise= $responses->promise();
        $promise->wait();
```

The code works well for unauthorization pages but if I need authorization for page then probably the authorization values isn't posted.

Thanks for helpful answers.